# Image name dropdown is empty when configuring remote interpreter Docker in PyCharm 2016

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

When configuring a Docker remote python interpreter in PyCharm 2016 with Docker for Mac OS X, the image name dropdown is empty.

[image: Configure Remote Python Interpreter]

The Image name field is mandatory and entering a value manually doesn't help. The same error messages is returned for 'python', 'python:3', 'python:3.5', 'library/python',...

[image]

Here is the PyCharm version info

[image]

And the Docker version info

[image]